# How to resync system user information with AD

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking for a tool or an easy way to update in bulk system users with the information originally found in the AD. There are some old tools online but they are still using the SOAP endpoint and I was hoping to find something that won't be deprecated in the next version.

I use CRM 2016 8.2.2 on-premise and nothing in my architecture is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution and adapted it to my needs. The script still used SOAP so instead I used Web API.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/hardworkdays/archive/2012/02/23/ms-crm-2011-bulk-refresh-of-user-details-from-ad